# How do you create and add a Zapier Zap action link?

Tags: zapier

I tried to look for this way of adding a Zap action into an HTML button either for a website or a rich email but I couldn't find one.

Obviosuly, adding a link to a button is very simple; but is there a way to create a such Zapier link? That will trigger a Zap.

Answer (score 1):

I believe webhook will trigger via a GET request with query params. So if you have an HTML button that sends the user to such a URL, it'll kick off an action.

You *should* also be able to use an `onClick` handler to call `fetch` to send a POST request to the webhook url. But, there may be CORS issues with this approach.